# why I get just numbers in UCS2 how can I fixed at commands and c#?

Tags: c#, sms, nokia, at-command

I am having a problem with reading my sms through putty, Its beacuse I type AT+CMGL="ALL" but the message(text) and number are just numbers, I read that my gms modem nokia s10 uses UCS2, but I dont know what to do here? how can I read my message intead of just seeing numbers?? help please

Also I am using this code from codeproject and I changed this line but It is the same result as putty just number in ucs2

```
 public ShortMessageCollection ReadSMS(SerialPort port, string p_strCommand)
    {

        // Set up the phone and read the messages
        ShortMessageCollection messages = null;
        try
        {

            #region Execute Command
            // Check connection
            ExecCommand(port,"AT", 300, "No phone connected");
            // Use message format "Text mode"
            ExecCommand(port,"AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
            // Use character set "PCCP437"
            **ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"", 300, "Failed to set character set.")**;
            // Select SIM storage
            ExecCommand(port,"AT+CPMS=\"SM\"", 300, "Failed to select message storage.");
            // Read the messages
            string input = ExecCommand(port, p_strCommand, 5000, "Failed to read the messages.");
            #endregion

            #region Parse messages
            messages = ParseMessages(input);
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        if (messages != null)
            return messages;
        else
            return null;    

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that `AT+CSCS` only affects *string* parameters to commands and responses. In the case of `AT+CMGL` the content of the message is not a string, but a `<data>` format. See the [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) specification for more details on that format, it is a bit complicated (only pay attention to the first `In the case of SMS` part, ignore the second `In the case of CBS` part).

But the short version of it is that for UCS-2 you will get the data hex encoded (e.g. two characters `'2'` and `'A'` represents one byte with value `0x2A` (ASCII/UTF-8 character `'*'`)). So you should decode 4 and 4 received bytes as the hex encoding of the 16 bits in a UCS-2 character.

So decode into a byte array and then convert to string, see Appleman1234's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749835/23118) for that (his answer does not address the core issue, namely the hex decoding).

Answer (score 0):

To convert from the UCS-2 encoding store the result (input) in a byte array instead of a string and then call

```
System.Text.Encoding enc =  Encoding.Unicode;
string myString = enc.GetString(myByteArray);
```

If the UCS-2 encoding is Big Endian then change `System.Text.Encoding enc =  Encoding.Unicode;` to 
`System.Text.Encoding enc =  Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;`.

Related resources include:

- [Unicode and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx)
- [C# big-endian UCS-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971593/c-sharp-big-endian-ucs-2)