# Receiving 7Bit binary SMS

Tags: sms, at-command, linefeed

I want to receive binary data over a 7-Bit encoded SMS to my PC/GPRS-Stick (XS Stick P14 from 4G Systems).
That works in principle fine, but if I send a binary `<linefeed>`-character (0x0A), the GPRS-stick will change this to:

`<carriage retrun>`+`<linefeed>`(0x0D0A)

Examle:

If I send this binary hex values: `000102030405060708090A0`

I get one Byte more: `000102030405060708090`**D0**`A0`

I don't understand this automatic replacement... Is it possibly not allowed to send `<linefeed>` -characters over 7-Bit SMS, or do I have to configure the modem via special at-commands?

Best Regards

Andreas

Comment: If you want to send binary over a 7 bit ASCII channel then it's a good idea to encode it as printable ASCII characters, e.g. [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding). That way you won't run into problems with control characters, and of course it takes care of the fact that you're missing bit 7.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting alternative approach, but I want to use the full SMS capacity, without any overhead if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are reading the received SMS with AT command `AT+CMGL` (or `AT+CMGR`), right? And I assume you are reading it in text mode (`AT+CMGF=1`). And within the returned `<data>` parameter your modem inserts an extra `\r` in front of `\n` if any.

The information text response for `AT+CMGL` is [specified](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) to have `"\r\n"` around the message content, e.g.

```
...<CR><LF><data>[<CR><LF>...
```

, and maybe the implementers felt uncomfortable having a single `\n` at the end and decided to drop that (or maybe it is a bug?). Does the insertion of `\r` happen for any placement of `\n`?

Interestingly 27.005 does not discuss what should happen if `<data>` contains `<CR><LF>`...
In [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) the following is said:

> 5.7.3 Information text formats for test commands
>
> In general, the format of information text returned by extended syntax commands shall
>   be specified in the definition of the command. ... Note that the DCE
>   may insert intermediate  characters in very long information text
>   responses, in order to avoid overrunning DTE receive buffers. If
>   intermediate  characters are included, the DCE shall not include
>   the character sequences "0 " (3/0, 0/13) or "OK" (4/15, 4/11,
>   0/13), so that DTE can avoid false detection of the end of these
>   information text responses.

Your scenario seems not to be too long response text, but
interestingly the DCE (aka modem) seems to be relatively
free to insert `<CR>` when it feels like.

Anyhow, if my assumption that you are reading in text mode is correct I would suggest to try to change the character set to hex (`AT+CSCS="HEX"`). That could make the modem behave differently with regards to `\r` insertion (or maybe not). If not you could try UCS-2 which also forces a hex response (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851012/23118)).

If none of this helps, you could change to read messages in PDU mode (e.g. `AT+CMGF=0`). That is just a raw dump of SMS message of every single bit that is transferred over the air, and I would be astonishingly shocked if the modem manages to insert any extra `\r` characters in there. You then end up having to decode that after having received it (not trivial, look for some already written library), but at least it should work.