# AT+CSCS="GSM" returning error

Tags: command, gsm, at-command, modem

My current setting is PCCP437 but with it no SMS related command is working like at+cmgl etc but when I try to use the at+cscs to change the encoding scheme it brings me an error.

Any ideas please ? PLEASE REFER TO THE LINK BELOW

THANKS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR1TS.png)

Comment: Please add the commands and output as text inside the question itself and not as a picture link.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work like you are doing, I know of no condition that switching character set like that should fail (various other commands failing or misbehaving in various ways afterwords is not unthinkable, but just switching to a supported character set really ought to work).

Is `GSM` the only character set that fails? Try switching to each of all the supported sets (except perhaps `HEX`, I do not think it will help you with regards to output. With it you have to parse the output to make it readable, and if you first are doing that you should definitely use `UCS2` instead. But it might be interesting to see if you are allowed to switch to it though).

Be aware that after switching to a given character set, you need to encode all strings this way, including switching to a new character set with `AT+CSCS`, like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672278/23118). I think all except HEX and UCS2 are compatible for the letters required to enter their names.

---

Regarding the output from `AT+CMGL`, notice that this is *not* affected by `AT+CSCS`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851012/23118) for details.