# Copy a Textfile to a new location and encode to ASCII

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following powershell script to copy a text file from one location to another and then encode it so that it can be imported using a SQL bulk copy.
The source file is encoded as UCS-2 Little Endian.

```
gc "\\SourceServer\Share\Person.txt" | Out-File -encoding ASCII \\dbserver\share\DataFlag\Person.txt
```

Can the same action be done in C# without using the powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971593/c-sharp-big-endian-ucs-2), there is no direct support for `UCS-2` in C#
But it should be possible to read the file using a `StreamReader` with `UTF-16` and compensate the differences by some additional byte-tweaking. Takes some research, though.

Comment: Thanks, I may stick with the powershell script for simplicity